# Python : tuple inside tuple get child index

Tags: python, tuples

i have this tuple:

```
STATUS = ((1, 'Standby'), (2, 'Approved'), (3, 'Rejected'))
```

The problem seems to be that this is a `tuple (x,x,x)` inside other tuple where `x` is `(i,'string')`. I need to get a index from the child tuple this is possible by doing this `STATUS[0].index('Standby')`

but this is not a good solution because i can't find directly by name.

So, i want to find the index directy without to mention what is the position of the tuple that i'm seeking.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by index? Do you want both the index of the tuple in which the element exists as well as the index of the element inside the inner tuple as well?

Comment: So, you want something like `STATUS.deepindex("Standby")` to yield `(0, 1)`?

Comment: Possibly related and/or duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/24419487/1639625

Comment: @tobias_k exactly! That's what i want. it seems that i need to make a function to do that, there is no out-of-the-box function to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a list and then use index?

```
STATUS = [None, 'Standby', 'Approved', 'Rejected']
STATUS.index('Standby')
```

returns 1

Comment: i know that a list is more easy, but i need to work with tuple. And i want to know if this is possible to attending to the example if this is possible.

Comment: Then just use STATUS = (None, 'Standby', 'Approved', 'Rejected')

Comment: I can't change the STATUS tuple, i need to work with it without modifying its structure because it have already some dependencies in my app

Answer (score 0):

Well,

it seems that doesn't exist any solution by default. So you need to do a function.
Using the suggestion of @tobias_k i made this possible solution.

```
def deepindex(mytuple,myvalue):
   for i in mytuple:
      if i.index(myvalue):
         return i.index(myvalue)

>>> deepindex(STATUS,'Standby')
>>> 1
```

Please if you find a better solution let me know. 
Thanks ;)

Answer (score 0):

Zip and map seems to be a good approach

zip: aggregates elements from each of the iterables (*STATUS) (see [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html))

map: to every item of iterable and return a list of the results (see [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map))

Using this two functions: you can get the index of a tuple inside another tuple as is described on this question as STATUS.

```
>>> a,b= map(list,zip(*STATUS))
>>> a[b.index('Standby')]
>>> 1
```

Comment: Answers should be more detailed than just a code snippet. Add some explanation.